# event.listener("timeupdate") is not equal to current time/4 because it runs every 250ms in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, dom, jquery-events

I have a project that displays something every quarter of the video.

To do this it takes the video duration and / 4. and then *2 for half, * 3 for 3 quarters.

It also does a timeupdate

```
if timeupdate = videoduration/4 then display content.
```

This is fine in firefox because timeupdate ticks every frame. But in Chrome timeupdate ticks every 250ms which means the function to display the content won't run because timeupdate is never = video duration/4.

I though rounding to a whole number would fix it but then this means that because it runs the function when timeupdate = videoduration/4 and it runs every 250ms in Chrome, the content is displayed 4 times per quarter.

Any ideas how i can fix this?

Edit - Code for reference:

```
video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {

perc = video.duration/4;
});


//  display the current and remaining times
video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function () {
    //  Current time  
    var vTime = video.currentTime;
perc1 = perc;
vTime1 = vTime;

if(vTime1 == perc1){
$('div.track').html('25%');

}
if(vTime1 == perc1+perc1){
$('div.track').html('50%');

}
if(vTime1 == perc1+perc1+perc1){
$('div.track').html('75%');

}
}, false);
```

Comment: So chrome doesn't return correct video duration or what? Improve your question by posting minimalistic sample code to reproduce your issue, thank you! And debug it on your own to check what's going wrong on chrome

Answer (score 0):

The `setTimeout`  is not guaranteed to run when you ask it to.  It should never run *earlier* but may run later.  You simply can't use it as a real-time counter.

In this case, the best thing you can do is keep track of how many times it has run... Rather than trying to match percents, match run times.

The other way is to you run your timer MUCH more often (every 50ms or so) and check and see if you have *passed* a timer-mark, and if so, your HTML then.

Comment: How would one go about running the timer more often? Would it be as simple as changing false to 50?

Comment: Hehe.. I just woke up when I posted that answer. Your timer should run often enough, so just change it to comparing if you are greater than a time, instead of comparing against it exactly.

Comment: I don't think that will work. because the timer will run every 250ms, it will check if its greater and say "yes" it is and then run the function over and over again. i just want the function to run once only. Is there something i can put in place that only runs an if statement once? even if the requirements are met four times?